# Calling ExecutorService.shutdownNow from CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, java-threads, completable-future

I need to cancel all scheduled but not yet running CompletableFuture tasks when one of already running task throws an exception.

Tried following example but most of the time the main method does not exit (probably due to some type of deadlock).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executionService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    Set< CompletableFuture<?> > tasks = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        final int id = i;
        CompletableFuture<?> c = CompletableFuture

        .runAsync( () -> {
            System.out.println("Running: " + id); 
            if ( id == 400 ) throw new RuntimeException("Exception from: " + id);
        }, executionService )

        .whenComplete( (v, ex) -> { 
            if ( ex != null ) {
                System.out.println("Shutting down.");
                executionService.shutdownNow();
                System.out.println("shutdown.");
            }
        } );

        tasks.add(c);
    }

    try{ 
        CompletableFuture.allOf( tasks.stream().toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new) ).join(); 
    }catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Got async exception: " + e); 
    }finally { 
        System.out.println("DONE"); 
    }        
}
```

Last printout is something like this:

```
Running: 402
Running: 400
Running: 408
Running: 407
Running: 406
Running: 405
Running: 411
Shutting down.
Running: 410
Running: 409
Running: 413
Running: 412
shutdown.
```

Tried running `shutdownNow` method on separate thread but it still, most of the time, gives the same deadlock.

Any idea what might cause this deadlock?

And what you think is the best way to cancel all scheduled but not yet running `CompletableFuture`s when exception is thrown?

Was thinking of iterating over `tasks` and calling `cancel` on each `CompletableFuture`. But what I dont like about this is that throws `CancellationException` from `join`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should keep in mind that

```
CompletableFuture<?> f = CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable, executionService);
```

is basically equivalent to

```
CompletableFuture<?> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
executionService.execute(() -> {
    if(!f.isDone()) {
        try {
            runnable.run();
            f.complete(null);
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            f.completeExceptionally(t);
        }
    }
});
```

So the `ExecutorService` doesn’t know anything about the `CompletableFuture`, therefore, it can’t cancel it *in general*. All it has, is some job, expressed as an implementation of `Runnable`.

In other words, `shutdownNow()` will prevent the execution of the pending jobs, thus, the remaining futures won’t get completed normally, but it will not cancel them. Then, you call `join()` on the future returned by `allOf` which will never return due to the never-completed futures.

But note that the scheduled job does check whether the future is already completed before doing anything expensive.

So, if you change your code to

```
ExecutorService executionService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
Set<CompletableFuture<?>> tasks = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
AtomicBoolean canceled = new AtomicBoolean();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    final int id = i;
    CompletableFuture<?> c = CompletableFuture
        .runAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("Running: " + id); 
            if(id == 400) throw new RuntimeException("Exception from: " + id);
        }, executionService);
        c.whenComplete((v, ex) -> {
            if(ex != null && canceled.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                System.out.println("Canceling.");
                for(CompletableFuture<?> f: tasks) f.cancel(false);
                System.out.println("Canceled.");
            }
        });
    tasks.add(c);
    if(canceled.get()) {
        c.cancel(false);
        break;
    }
}

try {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Got async exception: " + e);
} finally {
    System.out.println("DONE");
}
executionService.shutdown();
```

The runnables won’t get executed once their associated future has been canceled. Since there is a race between the cancelation and the ordinary execution, it might be helpful to change the action to

```
.runAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("Running: " + id); 
    if(id == 400) throw new RuntimeException("Exception from: " + id);
    LockSupport.parkNanos(1000);
}, executionService);
```

to simulate some actual workload. Then, you will see that less actions get executed after encountering the exception.

Since the asynchronous exception may even happen while the submitting loop is still running, it uses an `AtomicBoolean` to detect this situation and stop the loop in this situation.

---

Note that for a `CompletableFuture`, there is no difference between cancelation and any other exceptional completion. Calling `f.cancel(…)` is equivalent to `f.completeExceptionally(new CancellationException())`. Therefore, since `CompletableFuture.allOf` reports any exception in the exceptional case, it will be very likely a `CancellationException` instead of the triggering exception.

If you replace the two `cancel(false)` calls with `complete(null)`, you get a similar effect, the runnables won’t get executed for already completed futures, but `allOf` will report the original exception, as it is the only exception then. And it has another positive effect: completing with a `null` value is much cheaper than constructing a `CancellationException` (for every pending future), so the forced completion via `complete(null)` runs much faster, preventing more futures from executing.

Comment: Thanks. A few questions. Does it mean that calling `cancel` or `complete` on CompletableFuture will still not prevent `ExecutorService` from running it except in this case the CompletableFuture wont run the actual Runnable it was created with (due to `f.isDone()` being `true`)?
And by not using `shutdownNow` I should be able to reuse the `ExecutorService`, right?

Comment: Yes, in case of `runAsync`, the job will get scheduled immediately, so canceling the `CompletableFuture` does not prevent the job’s execution anymore, so it’s only the `isDone` pre-check which prevents the execution of your `Runnable`. That’s different to, e.g. `future2 = future1.thenApplyAsync(x -> x, executor)` where the job is only scheduled after the normal completion of `future1`, so if `future2` gets canceled before the completion of `future1`, the job won’t even get scheduled. Once being scheduled, the job’s behavior is similar. And yes, you can reuse the executor service now.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that relies only on `CompletableFuture` is to use a “canceller” future that will cause all non-done tasks to be cancelled when completed:

```
Set<CompletableFuture<?>> tasks = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
CompletableFuture<Void> canceller = new CompletableFuture<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (canceller.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Canceller invoked, not creating other futures.");
        break;
    }
    //LockSupport.parkNanos(10);
    final int id = i;
    CompletableFuture<?> c = CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> {
                //LockSupport.parkNanos(1000);
                System.out.println("Running: " + id);
                if(id == 400) throw new RuntimeException("Exception from: " + id);
            }, executionService);
    c.whenComplete((v, ex) -> {
        if(ex != null) {
            canceller.complete(null);
        }
    });
    tasks.add(c);
}
canceller.thenRun(() -> {
    System.out.println("Cancelling all tasks.");
    tasks.forEach(t -> t.cancel(false));
    System.out.println("Finished cancelling tasks.");
});
```

Comment: I left the `tasks` definition as-is, but actually this solution does not require a concurrent collection for the `tasks` since it will only be processed after it has been fully built (as long as the `canceller.thenRun()` code remains after the main loop).

Comment: `canceller.complete(null)`  can still be called while we are adding tasks. I think in your case we still need to have concurrent collection.

Comment: If `canceller.complete(null)` is called while building the tasks, the `thenRun()` will not have been registered yet. In that case the `thenRun()` lambda will actually be called on the thread that built the futures. That's why I indicated it must be after the main loop int my previous comment.